# A solution in a server/client program in JAVA

Tags: java, client-server

I hava a problem with my code. I make a server with Java which waits for connections. When a client connects, if we(the server) send the command "showinfo", the cliend send its IP address back to the server.

The problem is that it is a multi-threaded server and many clients connect. So, if, for example, 2 clients connect to the server we have to type 2 times showinfo and then the clients give us the information. How can I make the clients respond immediately with typing "showinfo" for each one and don't wait until I type showinfo for all the clients. It's a bit tiring to type 50 times showinfo if there are 50 clients before you can execute your command. Thank you in advance (i have tried some thread synchronization and some `sleep()` `join()` commands but I haven't reach a conclusion yet I hope you can help a bit.)

Here 's the server code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;

public class Server implements Runnable{  
    private Socket server;
    private static String command,info,message;
    BufferedReader infromclient =null;
    InputStream infromclient2=null;
    DataOutputStream outtoclient =null;
    static BufferedReader infrommaster=null;
    private static int port=6789;

    Server( Socket server ){
        try{    
            this.server=server;
            infromclient =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            outtoclient =new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            infrommaster=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }catch( IOException e ){
            System.out.println("Exception accessing socket streams: "+e);
        }
    }

    // main()
    // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadGroup clients = new ThreadGroup("clients");
        System.out.print("Waiting for connections on port " + port + "...");
        System.out.println("\nIn total there are:"+clients.activeCount()+" clients\n");
        try{
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket nextsocket;

            // waiting for connections
            while(true){
                nextsocket = server.accept();
                Thread client= new Thread(clients,new Server(nextsocket),"client"+(clients.activeCount()+1));
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                System.out.println("There are "+clients.activeCount()+" clients connected");
                client.start();                                
            }

        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }

    public void run (){                 
        try{                              
            command=infrommaster.readLine();  
            outtoclient.writeBytes(command+"\n");

            // showinfo
            if(command.equals("showinfo")){        
                info=infromclient.readLine();
                System.out.println("\nClient information\n\n" +info+"\n");                    
            }

            server.close();                         
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class Client{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String command2;
        String info;
        Socket clientSocket=null;
        Socket scket=null;    
        BufferedReader inFromUser=null;
        DataOutputStream outToServer=null;
        BufferedReader inFromServer=null;
        BufferedWriter tosite=null;

        try{
            clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), 6789);
            inFromUser =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            outToServer =new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            inFromServer =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));     
        }catch(UnknownHostException | IOException e ){
            System.out.println("Problem "+e);
        }                           

        command2=inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("From Server:" +command2);

        // showinfo
        if (command2.equals("showinfo")){
            try{
                InetAddress myip=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                info =("IP: " +myip.getHostAddress()+"\n");

                System.out.println("\nSome system information\n" + info);
                outToServer.writeBytes(info);           
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        outToServer.flush();
        outToServer.close();
        inFromUser.close();
        inFromServer.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

** the command `clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), 6789);` means that it tests my pc(my ip in port 6789) .

Answer (score 1):

If one thread is blocking on the readline, the other should eventually get control. That's the whole point of multithreading. I think I know your problem. Move the code where you are reading the input command into the run() method of the server instead. Then you should be good. I think the problem is that your threads are starting after you are polling for input.

Move these lines from the Server constructor to Server's run() method:

```
 infromclient =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            outtoclient =new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            infrommaster=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Comment: So as you say, if the client doesn't send the String info at the server how can it send its ip?

Comment: The client will still send it but it doesn't have to take it from the user.

Comment: Man this code is a small part of a biggest project that i make and the server is necessary to give some commands to its clients, that's why the user has to type. I tried some synchronization commands but the only thing i succeed was to make the other threads wait for the firtst and then the second etc thread to end its operation.I just want to ask you, is there another way,a command maybe to make the program more operational? I have also thought about multitasking/broadcasting but i don't know many things. Btw thank you for your answers

Comment: If I understand u correctly when your program goes live other people will be typing commands so this problem only exists in test, right? If so, you can get the threads to read commands from a file instead maybe? If this is not the case, then I don't really understand what your actual problem is.

Comment: Look.I am the server and i wait for clients to connect.Then i give them (to the clients) some commands.For example this "showinfo" command.When the clients receive "showinfo" they give their ip to me(server).I don't have a problem with the commands or the connection of the clients etc. My problem is with the code routine.For example 3 clients connect to the server and then i decide to send the showinfo command to the first.This cannot happen.If i type "showinfo" and hit enter nothing ll happen and the second client ll wait for its command.I give showinfo again and the third client waits too.

Comment: When i type showinfo for the third time all the clients give me their ip at last,but i wanted only the first ip.As i mentioned in my question just imagine to have 50 clients and want the ip of the first one.You have to type the command(and hit enter)50 times.If you execute the code you can understand my case.I believe that the problem is the readline() methods in the server side.Each thread which connects waits for commands so if you type showinfo for the first then you go to the readline() method of the second thread(client) etc.But there i got stuck...Thanks again for your help man

Comment: If one thread is blocking on the readline, the other should eventually get control. That's the whole point of multithreading. I think I know your problem. Move the code where you are reading the input command into the run() method of the server instead. Then you should be good. I think the problem is that your threads are starting after you are polling for input.

Comment: @user1195787 I've changed my answer to reflect the explanation.

Comment: @user1195787 Did it get fixed?

Comment: Sorry but i might not understand your answer.The code where i read the input command is into the run() method of the server.What do you mean?

Comment: @user1195787 Look at the updated answer. Basically take the user input in run() rather than the constructor of Server

Comment: Same again...Don't know which is the solution.I'm really stuck, but thanks for your answers.